# How to write part of header using BufferedOutputStream?

Tags: java, bufferedoutputstream

I want to write a ~20000 bytes to a replace the same number of bytes of file at offset OFFSET using a BufferedOutputStream. I try to do this with the following code:

```
headerOffset = 12000;
headerSize = 20000;
byte[] ba = new byte[20];
FileOutputStream os;
BufferedOutputStream bos;
try {
  os = new FileOutputStream('file.dat');
  bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
  bos.write(ba, headerOffset, headerSize);
  os.flush();
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

However, this results in the 'file.dat' being overwritten by the contents of ba overwriting the entire file and leaving it only as big as `ba`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Short answer; you don't. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html with NIO or `RandomAccessFile`

Comment: Use `RandomAccessFile`. See ***[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786697/how-to-write-content-in-a-specific-position-in-a-file)*** post

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I originally had used `RandomAccessFile` but felt it was too slow. Perhaps I was doing something wrong. Anyway, I'm going to revisit it and try to improve what I was trying to do earlier.