# Inserting a text at specific line number in a (.txt) file using java

Tags: java

```
 public void urlWriter(int y) throws IOException
            {
           File file = new File("C:\\DRIVE\\datas.txt");
           FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
           BufferedReader dummyReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

           BufferedWriter latestSource = new BufferedWriter(fw);


          //dummy string to read line by line
          String dooms =null;


         //loop for reading line by line
            for(i=0;i<y;i++) 
            {   
            while ((dooms=dummyReader.readLine())!=null)
            {


               //y line
                latestSource.write(CommonData.entered_direct);
                latestSource.newLine();
                //y+1 line
                latestSource.write(CommonData.entered_cellar);
                latestSource.newLine();
                //y+2 line
                latestSource.write(CommonData.entered_tele);
                latestSource.close();

            }
            }
```

*Tried to read line by line and then write at the specific locations. But the same issue exists.. Can some one help me out...????*

***Scenario** : if y value is passed as '4', the 4th,5th,6th line in the text file should be replaced with new data.Highly appreciable if some one helps me. Thanks in advance!!*

**Issue faced** :All the data is getting written at the bottom of the text file instead of sticking to the specified line number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can probably only achieved by reading the file line by line and then

- write the new text if it is one of the lines to be replaced.
- otherwise, write the original line.

You will then have the original file and a new file. You can rename them accordingly, this way you also have a backup of the last change.

Coarse outline:

```
 open input file (i.e. BufferedReader)
 open new outfile file (i.e. some Writer)
 line = 0
 data = read line from input
 while (there is data) 
    line = line + 1
    if (line >= y && line <= y+2)
        write replaced data
    else
        write data
    data = read line from input
close output file
close input file
```

Comment: Ya u r right. Accept your two thumb rule. but how to read line by line and write at the specific instance??

Comment: @DeepakPrabhu I'd recommend BufferedReader/BufferedWriter to do this.

Comment: i wil try to read line by line and write at the desired instance.. Thanks!

Comment: @Ingo.Tried as u instructed.                                     FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,true);Keeping it true , adds the data at the bottom. Keeping it false ,erases everything.What shall i do.

Comment: I will outline the algorithm, please be sure to follow.

Comment: Ok Ingo...I will work on it.

Comment: Remember, you can't do it "in line" (i.e. directly modifying the input file), unless the new data are exactly as long as the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

There's a class called RandomAccessFile, that's what your looking for.

Comment: Sorry i am not sure about those terminologies as i am new.

Comment: which terminology? class?

Comment: what does that "seek(15)" do?

Comment: searches for the 15th line in the file.

Comment: No, @JuanManuel, it goes to the 15th byte.

Comment: Cool!!.. Will check it right away.. Thanks!!

Comment: This will not help him

Comment: Will there be any conflict since multiple texts files are present with the same name?

Comment: @Jabir be welcome to post your solution.

Comment: how can the files have the same name?

Comment: if it is in different location...

Comment: @DeepakPrabhu but in your code are named differently..

Answer (score 0):

With help of `RandomAccessFile`[seek()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29) you can achieve that.

> Seek Sets the file-pointer offset, measured from the beginning of this
>   file, at which the next read or write occurs. The offset may be set
>   beyond the end of the file. Setting the offset beyond the end of the
>   file does not change the file length. The file length will change only
>   by writing after the offset has been set beyond the end of the file.

```
RandomAccessFile ra = new RandomAccessFile("abc.txt","rw" );// (file name, mode of file)
          ra.seek(15);// set the poss to overwrite
          ra.writeUTF("garbage");
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked and there is an answer which was accepted by the user. Please see following link [how to write content in a Specific position in a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786697/how-to-write-content-in-a-specific-position-in-a-file)