# How to overwrite file content at specific position in Java?

Tags: java, file, file-io

Im working on large file and I want to overwrite conent file at specific position, like this:

```
helloworld123456
```

overwrite new content "internet" at 6th word

```
hellointernet456
```

Thank you so much

edit:
RandomAccessFile can seek and write directly to file and its worked

```html
randomAccessFile.seek(5); 
randomAccessFile.write("internet".getBytes());
```

Comment: Read the file, make the change in memory, write the file

Comment: but i want write directly to the file, its very large file

Comment: Unless the file is seekable, that’s not how file I/o works

Comment: If it's a "large" file, then you will need to read in parts, make what ever modifications you need and write to out to a second file, when you're done, delete the original file and rename the second file into it's place

Comment: im found the way to do this :D by using RandomAccessFile i can seek to specific position, idk how effective but its worked, thank you for the answer
randomAccessFile.seek(5);
randomAccessFile.write("internet".getBytes());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered here:

> You can't insert data into a file. You can overwrite data at a specific location with RandomAccessFile. However an insert requires changing all of the data after it.

[how to write content in a Specific position in a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786697/how-to-write-content-in-a-specific-position-in-a-file)